# Restore Database "Restore failed for Server 'xxx' "

Tags: c#, sql, database, restore, database-restore

I have a problem. I tried the code like belov. But i am getting exception. and the exception is :

```
"Restore failed for Server 'SMART0090\SQL2008RR2'."  FailedOperationException. .... the error is at "restore.SqlRestore(server);" line
```

What do you think about the problem? The code is :

```
public void RestoreToDatabase(string NewDatabaseName, string BackUpFile, string ServerName, string UserName, string Password)
    {
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(ServerName, UserName, Password);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(connection);
        Database database = new Database(server, NewDatabaseName);
        database.Create();

        database.Refresh();

        Restore restore = new Restore();

        restore.NoRecovery = false;

        restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

        BackupDeviceItem bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);

        bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(BackUpFile, DeviceType.File);

        restore.Devices.Add(bdi);

        restore.Database = NewDatabaseName;

        restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

        restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;

        restore.SqlRestore(server);

        database.Refresh();

        database.SetOnline();

        server.Refresh();
    }
```

EDIT : All exception message is just this : [image]

Thanks For your advice....

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: What is teh inner exception? The one that is generated by SQL Server?

Comment: What is in the View Detail of the error?  Have you checked the event log on the machine?  Have you checked SQL server logs through management studio?

Comment: i havent any log on machine, and the view detail is same, there is not any information or some thing like that. the error is : "Restore failed for Server 'SMART0090\SQL2008RR2". I havent any evidence :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. The error is : when you restore a *.bak file, the *.mdf and *.ldf files are copied to a special directory. Forexample : when I restore a *.bak file my *.mdf and *.ldf files copied under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008RR2\MSSQL\DATA\". So : If there is same name for *.mdf or *.ldf file, you can get exception like i did. And I solve it with change *.mdf and *.ldf files path. I write belov code and it's working.

**The C# code is :**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Var olan backup ın restore edilmesini sağlar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="NewDatabaseName">new database name</param>
    /// <param name="BackUpFile">backup file path</param>
    /// <param name="ServerName">server name</param>
    /// <param name="UserName">user name</param>
    /// <param name="Password">password</param>
    public void RestoreToDatabase(string NewDatabaseName, string BackUpFile, string ServerName, string UserName, string Password, string restorePath)
    {
        string provider = "Server    =" + ServerName +
                   ";Database =" + "master" +
                   ";User Id  =" + UserName +
                   ";password =" + Password +
                   "; Connect Timeout=2" +
                   ";Trusted_Connection=False";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(provider);

        try
        {
            string ConnectionString = @"Data Source= " + ServerName + ";Initial Catalog=AudioMaster;Integrated Security=True";
            ServerConnection ServerConn = null;
            if (UserName == "" && Password == "")
            {
                ServerConn = new ServerConnection(ServerName);
            }
            else if (UserName != "" && Password != "")
            {
                ServerConn = new ServerConnection(ServerName, UserName, Password);
            }

            Server server = null;

            RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
            String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");

            server = new Server(ServerConn);
        first:
            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db in server.Databases)
            {
                if (NewDatabaseName == db.Name)
                {
                    UpdateScreen("> Same database name detected", Color.Red);
                    NewDatabaseName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(NewDatabaseName + " database allready exist. Please enter new database name ",
                    "Database owerride error", "Enter a name");
                    UpdateScreen("> New database name : " + NewDatabaseName, Color.Green);
                    goto first;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError(ex);
            UpdateScreen("> An error ocurred when database names searching operation. Details : " + ex.Message, Color.Red);
        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            top :
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dirDebug, "scriptTry.txt"));
            string mdfName = String.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Path", BackUpFile);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RestorePath", restorePath);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@databaseName", NewDatabaseName);

            mdfName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            string[] names = Directory.GetFiles(restorePath, "*.mdf");

            int sayac = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<names.GetLength(0); i++) 
            {
                if (mdfName == GetSubPath(names[i].Replace(".mdf", "")))
                    sayac++;
            }

            if (sayac !=0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter new directory for database *.mdf and *.ldf file", "Database owerride error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                try
                {
                    UpdateScreen("> Same path detected for *.mdf and *.ldf file.", Color.Red);
                    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                    fbd.ShowDialog();
                    if (fbd.SelectedPath == "")
                        return;
                    else
                    {
                        restorePath = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\";
                    }
                    UpdateScreen("> Selected new path for *.mdf and *.ldf file : " + fbd.SelectedPath, Color.Green);
                    goto top; 
                }
                catch (Exception exx)
                {
                    WriteError(exx);
                    UpdateScreen("> An error ocurred when database restore. Details : " + exx.Message, Color.Red);
                }
            }

            file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dirDebug, "backup script.txt"));

            cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Path", BackUpFile);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RestorePath", restorePath);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@databaseName", NewDatabaseName);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError(ex);
        }
    }
```

**The "scriptTry.txt" SQL Code is :**

```
use master

--DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(1000)= 'C:\bekap.bak',
--        @RestorePath NVARCHAR(max) = 'C:\New folder\',
--        @databaseName VARCHAR(1000)= 'isim'

DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
      LogicalName VARCHAR(128) ,
      [PhysicalName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Type] VARCHAR ,
      [FileGroupName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Size] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [MaxSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [CreateLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DropLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [UniqueId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadOnlyLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadWriteLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [BackupSizeInBytes] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [SourceBlockSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileGroupId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [LogGroupGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsReadOnly] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsPresent] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [TDEThumbprint] VARCHAR(128)
    )

DECLARE @LogicalNameData VARCHAR(128) ,
    @LogicalNameLog VARCHAR(128)
INSERT  INTO @table
        EXEC ( '
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' + @Path + '''
   '
            )

DECLARE @restoreScript NVARCHAR(max)='RESTORE DATABASE [' + @databaseName + '] FROM DISK =''' + @Path + ''' WITH FILE = 1 '

SELECT  @restoreScript +=CHAR(10) + ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + 
        @RestorePath  + LogicalName + RIGHT(PhysicalName,4) + ''''
                         FROM   @Table
                         WHERE  Type = 'D'

 SELECT  @restoreScript += ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + @RestorePath  + LogicalName + '.ldf'''
                        FROM    @Table
                        WHERE   Type = 'L'

SET @restoreScript += ' , NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10 '

--SELECT  @restoreScript
select LogicalName from @Table
--EXEC  (@restoreScript)
```

**The "backup script.txt" SQL Code is :**

```
use master

--DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(1000),
--        @RestorePath NVARCHAR(max),
--        @databaseName VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
      LogicalName VARCHAR(128) ,
      [PhysicalName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Type] VARCHAR ,
      [FileGroupName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Size] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [MaxSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [CreateLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DropLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [UniqueId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadOnlyLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadWriteLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [BackupSizeInBytes] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [SourceBlockSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileGroupId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [LogGroupGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsReadOnly] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsPresent] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [TDEThumbprint] VARCHAR(128)
    )

DECLARE @LogicalNameData VARCHAR(128) ,
    @LogicalNameLog VARCHAR(128)
INSERT  INTO @table
        EXEC ( '
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' + @Path + '''
   '
            )

DECLARE @restoreScript NVARCHAR(max)='RESTORE DATABASE [' + @databaseName + '] FROM DISK =''' + @Path + ''' WITH FILE = 1 '

SELECT  @restoreScript +=CHAR(10) + ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + 
        @RestorePath  + LogicalName + RIGHT(PhysicalName,4) + ''''
                         FROM   @Table
                         WHERE  Type = 'D'

 SELECT  @restoreScript += ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + @RestorePath  + LogicalName + '.ldf'''
                        FROM    @Table
                        WHERE   Type = 'L'

SET @restoreScript += ' , NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10 '

--SELECT  @restoreScript
EXEC  (@restoreScript)
```