# Restore database of more than 10MB size using C# showing error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using this command For restoring my database using C#

```
private void btn_restore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        intializeConnections();
        intializeDataServer();

        if ((txt_bakfile.Text.ToString()!="") &&(txt_bakfile.Text !="System.Data.DataRow"))
        {
            Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(frmWaitShow));
          //  clsLogs.LogEvent(4, "Tread is call");

            oThread.Start();
            // Create a new database restore operation
            Restore rstDatabase = new Restore();
            // Set the restore type to a database restore
            rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            // Set the database that we want to perform the restore on
            rstDatabase.Database = DatabaseName;

            // Set the backup device from which we want to restore, to a file
            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(txt_bakfile.Text.ToString(), DeviceType.File);
            // Add the backup device to the restore type
            rstDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
            // If the database already exists, replace it
            rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            // Perform the restore
            rstDatabase.SqlRestore(srvSql);
            oThread.Abort();  
        }
    }
```

Function are :

```
    public void intializeConnections()
    {
        string connString = SqlHelper.ConString;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
        serverName = builder.DataSource;
         DatabaseName = builder.InitialCatalog;
        UserId = builder.UserID;
        pw = builder.Password;

    }

    private void intializeDataServer()
    {

      // Create a new connection to the selected server name
        ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(serverName);
        // Log in using SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication
        srvConn.LoginSecure = false;
        // Give the login username
        srvConn.Login = UserId;
        // Give the login password
        srvConn.Password = pw;
        // Create a new SQL Server object using the connection we created
        srvSql = new Server(srvConn);
    }
```

This works perfectly for my all databases which have a size of less than 10MB, but when I am trying to restore my one database which has size of more than 10MB, it's showing an error

> Restore failed for Server 'VARUN-PC'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14813523/

Comment: Can you post the full exception that you are getting please?

Comment: @P_G thanks for your attention.. I updated My Question,

Comment: are you sure it's really 10MB and not 10GB? 10MB is quite small for a database ... and 10GB could be a problem with sql server express ... I think express databases are limited to less than 10GB ...

Comment: What message is in "View Detail..." link of the exception?

Comment: @Endrju I updated My Question .. Kindly check it

Comment: There should be "Message" node. Try to find it and post it here. Don't have to be a screenshot, just a copy of the text in it.